# Django-keyboard-shortcuts

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.0

I add Django-keyboard-shortcuts to my INSTALLED_APPS, following the description in the official website, but I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Model class photo.models.Data doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

My INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'photo.apps.PhotoConfig',
    'keyboard_shortcuts',
     ....
]
```

And I got the error when:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Share your installed_apps(in settings.py) and also the exact file where you're getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works, I found the error in .../lib/python3.5/site-packages/keyboard_shortcuts/__init__.py:

```
except Exception, e:
```

I remove the `,e`